# How to configure RadioButton grouping

Tags: maui

I am developing a dynamic test designer program. To dynamically create and modify designer elements, a `CollectionView` and a combined `DataTemplate` are used, which is defined as a resource at the page level.

First let's move on to Model

This class represents an `ItemsSource CollectionView` in which `IsGrouped="True"`

```
public class Question : ObservableCollection<IItem>
    {
        public Question() { }

        public Question(IEnumerable<IItem> items) : base(items)
        {
            
        }

        private string questionName;
        public string QuestionName
        {
            get => questionName;
            set => questionName = value;
        }     
    }
```

These classes represent objects that are stored in the Question class and the `DataTemplate` is built from them.

```
public class CheckBoxItem : IItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => text = value;
        }

        private bool correctAnswer = false;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => correctAnswer = value;
        }

        public (string, int) IItem;

        public bool Compare(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is CheckBoxItem cb)
            {
                if (correctAnswer == cb.correctAnswer)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

public class RadioButtonItem : IItem
    {
        private string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => text = value;
        }

        private bool correctAnswer = false;
        public bool CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => correctAnswer = value;
        }

        public bool Compare(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is RadioButtonItem rb)
            {
                if (correctAnswer == rb.correctAnswer)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

public class TextItem : IItem
    {
        private string correctAnswer;
        public string CorrectAnswer
        {
            get => correctAnswer;
            set => correctAnswer = value;
        }

        public bool Compare(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is TextItem ti)
            {
                if (correctAnswer == ti.correctAnswer)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(EditTest), "EditTest")]
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Test), "Test")]
    public partial class CreateTestPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public CreateTestPageViewModel(IFileService fileService)
        {
            this.fileService = fileService;
            Test = new Test();
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Test test;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool editTest;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private Question selectedQestion;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private IItem selectedItem;

        private readonly IFileService fileService;

        #region COMMANND
        [RelayCommand]
        private void CreateQuestionCheckBoxItems() => AddAnyQuestion(new CheckBoxItem());

        [RelayCommand]
        private void CreateQuestionRadioButtomItems() => AddAnyQuestion(new RadioButtonItem());

        [RelayCommand]
        private void CreateQuestionTextItems() => AddAnyQuestion(new TextItem());

        [RelayCommand]
        private void RemoveQuestion(Question question) => Test.Questions.Remove(question);

        [RelayCommand]
        private void SelectiondItemChange(Question question)
        {
            SelectedQestion = question;
            SelectedQestion.Remove(selectedItem);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void AddItem(Question question)
        {
            SelectedQestion = question;
            var item = (IItem)Activator.CreateInstance(question[0].GetType());            
            question.Add(item);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void RemoveItem(IItem item)
        {
            var check = Test.Questions.Where(x => x.Contains(item)).Select(x => x.Remove(item));
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private void CreateTest()
        {
            AddTest();
            Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MainPage));           
        }
        #endregion

        #region METHODS
        private void AddAnyQuestion<T>(T item)
            where T : IItem, new()
        {
            Question question = new Question(new ObservableCollection<IItem>() {item});
            question.QuestionName = test.Questions.Count().ToString();
            Test.Questions.Add(question);
        }

        private void AddTest()
        {
            if(EditTest)
            {
                fileService.DeleteFile(Test.PathFile);
                Test.PathFile = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + $"/{Test.Name}.txt";
                fileService.Save(Test);
            }
            else
            {
                Test.PathFile = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + $"/{Test.Name}.txt";
                fileService.Save(Test);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

The code itself is the `CreateTestPage` page on which, using buttons, you can dynamically create questions of the Question class to choose from with `CheckBox`, `RadioButton` and Text, and also dynamically change the number of these elements.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplateCheckBox" x:DataType="model:CheckBoxItem">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ch" IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Editor x:Name="ed" IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" Background="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Fill" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"  Placeholder="Enter your answer" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="RemoveItem" Background="White" Source="/Images/del.png"
                         Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path=RemoveItemCommand}"
                         CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplateRadioButton" x:DataType="model:RadioButtonItem">
                <HorizontalStackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Context}">
                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Editor IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" Background="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Fill" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"  Placeholder="Enter your answer" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <ImageButton x:Name="RemoveItem" Background="White" Source="/Images/del.png"
                             Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path=RemoveItemCommand}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ListTemplateText" x:DataType="model:TextItem">
                <HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Editor IsTextPredictionEnabled="True" Background="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Fill" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True"  Placeholder="Enter your answer" Text="{Binding CorrectAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <ImageButton BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="RemoveItem" Source="/Images/del.png"
                             Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path= RemoveItemCommand}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <templates:CreateTestTemplate x:Key="ItemSelector" CheckBox="{StaticResource ListTemplateCheckBox}"
                                      RadioButton="{StaticResource ListTemplateRadioButton}"
                                      Text="{StaticResource ListTemplateText}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.15*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                <Button Text="CreateTest" Command="{Binding CreateTestCommand}"/>
                <Editor Text="{Binding Test.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

        <CollectionView x:Name="Qestions" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Test.Questions}"                     
                        SelectionMode="None" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="1" IsGrouped="True" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemSelector}">

            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Question">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <Editor Placeholder="Enter a question title" Text="{Binding QuestionName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <ImageButton  Source="/Images/del.png" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path= RemoveQuestionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

            <CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:CreateTestPageViewModel">
                    <ImageButton HorizontalOptions="Center" Source="/Images/plus.png" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path= AddItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupFooterTemplate>

            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="1" Orientation="Vertical" BindingContext="{x:Reference Qestions}"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        </CollectionView>

        <Border Background="White" Grid.Row="{Binding Test.Questions.Count}" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 25,0,25,0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Button BackgroundColor="Red" Command="{Binding CreateQuestionCheckBoxItemsCommand}"/>
                <Button BackgroundColor="Red" Command="{Binding CreateQuestionRadioButtomItemsCommand}"/>
                <Button BackgroundColor="Red" Command="{Binding CreateQuestionTextItemsCommand}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

[github](https://github.com/Kowari1/TestBuilder)

I tried to configure RadioButtonGroup by overriding

```
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="1" Orientation="Vertical" BindingContext="{x:Reference Qestions}"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

On the side there are red buttons that create a question with one element checkBox RadioButton and Text, in this case I pressed the middle button 2 times and created 2 questions with RadioButton
[2 questions with RadioButton (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHnZN.jpg)

Under them there is a + button and it adds another answer option
[adding a RadioButton answer option (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6l1S.jpg)
The problem is that I don’t know How can I group RadioButton by questions.

Comment: `But this did not help because the DataTemplate elements do not see the page elements, even though it is defined at the page level.` Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on what your problem is? What kind of effect do you want?

Comment: Hello, I updated the question and added detailed information from the bottom of the image, I also managed to access elements outside the DataTemplate but could not solve the problem

Comment: `The problem is that I don’t know How can I group RadioButton by questions ` Do you mean that your newly added internal sub-problems doesn't show up?

Comment: When adding a question with a RadioButton, I want to group all the buttons within each question separately. In the second image, you can see that I added 2 questions with a RadioButton and if you click on the RadioButton and then change it to another one inside the same question, then the checkbox from the previous one will not disappear, since there is no grouping, I can make a grouping that will work for all RadioButtons in general, but I need them to be grouped within their question.

Comment: The application presents a dynamic test designer where the user can use red buttons to add as many questions of different types as he wants and add as many answer options as he wants inside the question. Now I can’t create a RadioButton grouping inside the questions. The images and accompanying text show the mechanics of dynamic test creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding CorrectAnswer, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <RadioButton.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:CreateTestPageViewModel}}, Path=RadioButtonChekcedCommand}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </RadioButton.GestureRecognizers>
                </RadioButton>
```

```
[RelayCommand]
        private void RadioButtonChekced(RadioButtonItem item)
        {
            var items = Test.Questions.Single(x => x.Contains(item));

            foreach (RadioButtonItem item2 in items)
            {
                 item2.CorrectAnswer = false;
            }            
            item.CorrectAnswer = true;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).